# Find the string pattern in string

Tags: mysql

I have a table called "tempData" where I have a column "rawData" in which I have text value.

E.g. - "One value is AT0001 and another value is - AT0002 in a column other might be AT0005 ok"

I want to fetch the text AT0001, AT0002, AT0005 and put it into another table as a new row.

I tried

`REGEX_SUBSTR ("One value is AT0001 and another value is - AT0002 in a column other might be AT0005 ok", "AT....")`

But it only return "AT0001". I want all the values.

How can I get that?

Thanks,

Atul

Comment: which version of mysql/ariadb are you using?

Comment: I would do this in a proper programming language, not in sql.

Comment: @nbk, I am using Mysql8

Comment: Why dont you simply use LIKE 'AT000%' ?

Comment: It wont give the values what I want. I am not going to search it but to find it.

Comment: the only way i can see is a loop in a stored procedure where you run your REGEX_SUBSTR  ('text','pattern',1,i) and check if something comes back and concat it if so

Comment: @nbk, thanks. Let me try.

Comment: try a function that returns text, so you can run over a bunch of rows, but don't ask for performance